# Is it possible to open a link in IE from Firefox?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

I'm working on a project that is planned to be published as a Firefox add-on. One segment of the project, though, requires a link to be opened in Internet Explorer. I've done some research, and so far the only results that have turned up that accomplish this are add-ons to Firefox. We're trying to avoid having to use one of these, as we want the installation process for our users to be as easy as possible. So, is there any sort of workaround for this? I know this is horrible practice, but the only solution I could think of, if it is even possible, is to change the user's default browser to IE before the link is opened, then switch it back after the page has loaded. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing your own Firefox add-on, you can use [nsIProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIProcess) and related to launch an iexplore.exe process.  You can pass the url on the command line.

Please do not change the user's preferences.  :)

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it should be what we need! We're still a few steps off from implementing this, but I'll be sure to let you know if it works. I thought that changing the user's preferences was probably one of the worst solutions to this problem, so I thought something better would come up.

Comment: Yup.  The page has examples of launching a process from javascript down at the bottom, so it should be a simple cut and paste job into your extension.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I'm about to start trying to work this into our solution now.

Comment: Ok, I've run into a problem. When I try to simply open IE at the beginning of my script, I get this error:

    Permission denied for <website here> to get property XPCComponents.classes

What does this mean, and is there anyway around this?

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on. We haven't packaged our code together as an add-on yet, so it doesn't have permission to start a process. I'll give this a go again when we actually have it as an add-on, but thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hmm, there may be a command line option to disable security checks.  I'm not sure.  I know Chrome supports such a thing.  A quick internet search turned up nothing for me though.

Comment: Yeah, same for me. It makes sense that a website isn't able to start a process on your computer. I'm pretty sure there is a preference that you can enable to allow XPCOM controls, but we'd like to avoid messing with our users' preferences, so we'll just wait to implement this for now. Again, thanks for your help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Oh yeah, it would be a developer-only change, just to make this stage of your life easier.